# Azure Devops - How to get published information of a wiki page using Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I referred this Microsoft document "[MS Rest API documentation for wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)" and was able to get all the pages available in wiki. I was trying to get the **published author and published time** related information for which there is no available reference.

Is there any Azure DevOps Rest API available to get this information?

Comment: Have you tried testing any of this through Fiddler? If you navigate through the UI and have Fiddler running in the background, I've found I've been able to capture some early-release API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Devops - How to get published information of a wiki page using Rest API

I am afraid there is no such REST API at this moment, however you can track it by tools such as Fiddler or press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome browser then select `Network`.

On the web UI, we could access the `View revisions` of the Wiki:

[image]

We could get the history of this Wiki:

[image]

Then we press <kbd>F12</kbd> and click the first history, we could get the REST API like below:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/<WikiName>/Commits/<CommitsId>?
```

[image]

**But**, if we want to automate it by REST API, This seems impossible at the moment.

To automate it, we need to get the first commit ID for the Wiki, I could use the REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/<WikiName>/Commits/?
```

Now, I could get the all the commits, but those commits for all Wiki files, and there are no other parameters that can be used to filter out which wiki document the commit is associated with. So, we could not get the first commit for each wiki automatically. That is the current limitation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get commits from specific pages: searchCriteria.itemPath=
Here is doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Wiki page path will be: /WikiName/Folder--Name/Page-Name.md
Keep in mind that space in page name or folder name you need to replace with '-'. Also add extension to the page '.md'